# Why is adding a Rails middleware like this causing endless redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, middleware, puma

I'm trying to add some middleware to a Rails project I'm working on, and when I try to do so, it seems to cause an endless loop.

Specifically, I have the following middleware shell file:

```
# app/middleware/log_data.rb

class LogData
    def initialize(app)
        @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
        # To-do: Write code here.
    end
end
```

I then created a new `middleware` directory under the `app` directory and put the file in that directory.

After that, I added the following towards the bottom of `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use("LogData")
```

After restarting the Puma server running on Vagrant with `sudo service puma restart`, if I run `rake middleware`, I can see the middleware correctly show up in the list towards the bottom.

However, when I try to refresh the website, it fails with an endless loop, displaying the following in Chrome:

[image]

If I comment out the `config.middleware.use("LogData")` line in `config/application.rb`, then the middleware disappears from the `rake middleware` command list, and the website stops crashing and loads properly.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? I imagine it's something simple, but I'm not sure why a simple (and empty) shell middleware file would cause the whole site to crash. Thank you.

I should note that I'm using Rails 4.2.11, which I know is old, but upgrading right now is not an option.

Comment: Please show what `call(env)` looks like. The problem might be in there.

Comment: What I have written above is literally what I have. I was trying to set up a shell first before going any further, but the shell as-is is crashing everything. I trying adding a random model fetch (like `User.find(1)`), but that seems to make no difference.

Comment: Let's put `@app.call(env)` in `def call(env)`. I'll add the answer after you check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your middleware does nothing, returns nil (which translates to an Incomplete Server Response), and basically the request ends there. It needs to return something (an array of `[status, headers, response]`, or call the env) to allow the request to pass through the middleware chain.

```
# app/middleware/log_data.rb

class LogData
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

   def call(env)
    # To-do: Write code here.
    
    # this should be at the very end of the method
    @app.call(env)
   end
end
```

[Here](https://blog.engineyard.com/understanding-rack-apps-and-middleware) is more info about middlewares.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I tried `[status, headers, response]` and `[@status, @headers, @response]`, and got various errors in both cases (probably because I wasn't properly defining those variables, but `@app.call(env)` worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.